# TypeScript: testing conditional type equality - understanding the syntax

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I've been experimenting with comparing the equality of types within TypeScript.  I've happened upon this approach:

```
type SomeType = {
  property: string;
}

type OtherType = {
  property: string;
}

/**
 * The two types passed are evaluated for equivalence; returning true if they
 * are equivalent types and false if not
 * 
 * Based upon Matt McCutchen's comment:
 * https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650
 */
type Equals<Type1, Type2> =
    (<Type1Match>() => Type1Match extends Type1 ? "match!" : "not a match") extends
    <Type2Match>() => Type2Match extends Type2 ? "match!" : "not a match"
    ? true
    : false;

type IsTrue<T extends true> = T

/**
 * This expression will evaluate that our types match; note
 * the underscore at the start which indicates this is expected
 * to be an unused type 
 */
type test = IsTrue<Equals<SomeType, OtherType>
```

I'm reading and re-reading `Equals` above and I'm slightly puzzled by the `<Type1Match>() =>`  at the start of `(<Type1Match>() => Type1Match extends Type1 ? "match!" : "not a match")`.

There doesn't appear to be a function in the mix here; or is there and am I missing something? Is this just a backdoor way to introduce a new generic?

#### Update following Titians's excellent answer

The unfortunate thing about Titian's updated (and clearer) approach is that it doesn't handle all type equivalence checks well.  Consider `any` comparisons where Titian's `Equals2` fails to detect differences.  The same is true for another simplified `Equals3` that I put together.

But `Equals` does succeed in detecting these issues.  The question in my mind is "why does this work?" and also "can I rely on this moving forwards?". So, if I've got code that depends upon being able to perform this equality check, am I building upon shifting sand here?  Does this approach rely upon a compiler implementation detail that might change in future?

[See in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gKClMAJzkkNAC4oBDAOxAG4cBfHHUSKAeWAAsJDUHTLnxES-ClADOwQgEsaAc0YscAegBUGvBqjI+UYAHc4htFIJUpUiABNqhaBABuVADYBXKsDtQAZnCEUBAAjh5yrm4QNADGEPRQjsAehDQKioaEHtByfoZ8IDoOTmER7tHAZpAWtPZ+7jZQuVA0cMBFRQBCVr4eYHA0UACy3pVDMQDCHsAxfDQA5BYxiEg0wORFPMDAYFLkamqKcrweAEYAdMsIaghyMcRScH7AaoIQMPdyYC9y1tlSagATAB2AAMgIALABiX5SbJXVbAAC0EMBAEYAKyAgCcADYMaCdGo2GgoABRMINAA8bzRABo9GhAQA+KDoPD4KAAChpaDRIxmPGZXIAlGzWbSBbNggAPHw0WwWWlQAD8UAARAhvLMAITqqCUdWtSpUKBawXqsUQOXRRUc-C8yCAqVC0XixlOl2y+WKj0QQGqjXm3X6w3G6hm7U8dX2wOybKxyj1Nw2RisdjQCleFOAx0Qel+lls2M8yVR722pV84Vi9ASvkuq02hUWUtMr3Wn1Vp0191vZ1RkWxtXxiCJ-wNeLp0lZhoAZjzBf7rPZnKgAG1aQBdCstjf9ndqrk4ACQJ83TJ3ncr+75h8y2QNE5TY5PYqTk7TGagAEkpMgsggGld19UcVz0VhNG0KBdH0X5ZSICBrDkAYoCMOQ3DcYJIi8Hx8m8KA4BSKokMjQUEmNMcYPyaAPAVfgpGWRxqEqXhoBkKgyDQng7h4JoFTubxSN4eD4OtSAYh8WwimAUxTmgWgoDojwbHsb8iRJDgfBkNlf3-QCqVnFMqXgJA3gZbg+AENBmWZTToG04AA0wP8AOyQzKRzEzEBQNALLY6zIFs+zDCQ4A5101yDKMqQF1M3zIH8qy3lsoA)

```
type SomeType = {
  property: any;
}

type OtherType = {
  property: string;
}

/**
 * The two types passed are evaluated for equivalence; returning true if they
 * are equivalent types and false if not
 * 
 * Based upon Matt McCutchen's comment:
 * https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650
 */
type Equals<Type1, Type2> =
    (<Type1Match>() => Type1Match extends Type1 ? "match!" : "not a match") extends
    <Type2Match>() => Type2Match extends Type2 ? "match!" : "not a match"
    ? true
    : false;


type Equals2<Type1, Type2> =
    (<Type1Match extends Type1>() => Type1Match) extends (<Type2Match extends Type2>() => Type2Match)
    ? true
    : false;

type Equals3<Type1, Type2> =
    [Type1] extends [Type2] ? (
        [Type2] extends [Type1] ? true : false
    ) : false;

type IsTrue<T extends true> = T

/**
 * This expression will evaluate that our types match; note
 * the underscore at the start which indicates this is expected
 * to be an unused type 
 */
type test = IsTrue<Equals<SomeType, OtherType>> // errors as the types are not equivalent
type test2 = IsTrue<Equals2<SomeType, OtherType>> // unfortunately does not error
type test3 = IsTrue<Equals3<SomeType, OtherType>> // unfortunately does not error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Type1Match>() => Type1Match extends Type1 ? "match!" : "not a match"` is actually a function signature and `Type1Match` is a type parameter to the function signature. Removing the conditional type from the return type makes it a bit more clear `<Type1Match>() => SomeReturnType`. The return type is a conditional type `Type1Match extends Type1 ? "match!" : "not a match"` (which does make it indeed very difficult to read).

The reason for all of this is that TS uses the equivalence comparison in a very limited number of places. This is one of them, in conditional types that involve type parameters.

Comment: @Titan Cernovica-Dragomir do you know other places where TS uses the equivalence comparison? Some time ago I spent several days to understand  McCutchen's comment ))

Comment: @captain-yossarian I don't really know a list.. it's you'll know it when you discover it kinds situation :(

Comment: This is great Titian! I prefer your Equals over the original for clarity reasons.

Comment: I have a follow on question which I'll add into the original above!

Comment: @JohnReilly I was wrong about the other version of of `Equals`, my bad :( I removed it from the answer